Tight bound proof
Suppose that for a classifier, the worst-case error rate is shown to be $\leq \frac{1}{4}$. I want to prove that $\frac{1}{4}$ is a tight upper bound.
To do so, my approach is that it is sufficient to find a specific case under which $\frac{1}{4}$ is reached exactly. However, I was only able to show that this error rate probability, as a function of $\epsilon$, tends to $\frac{1}{4}$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, i.e. $p(\epsilon)\rightarrow \frac{1}{4}$.
My question is whether my approach is correct and also whether this is sufficient as a demonstration of tightness or not. If so, any reference in this regard would be helpful as well.
Thanks a ton!

Yes, the approach is correct. More formally, you are showing that for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists an instance such that the error of the classifier is at least $1/4 - \varepsilon$, which shows that the worst case error has to be greater than $1/4 - \varepsilon$.

@sudeep5221 Thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate what the instance is? Also, is there any reference I can read more details on proving such tight bounds in limit?

The instance is the one that you mentioned where you show that the error rate probability goes to $1/4$ as $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$. I assumed that you established the relation by creating a particular probability distribution. If not, then you'll need to provide some additional details about the problem and how you were able to show relation on probability of error. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a particular reference that discusses proving these kinds of bounds.

@sudeep5221 Thanks for clarification. Yes, my demonstration is based on a probability distribution.

$1/4$ can be maximally tight even if it cannot be obtained; it might, for instance, simply be a lowest upper bound. It's possible you already understand this, but I wanted to make it clear on the off chance you didn't think this was possible.

@BrianTung Thanks Brian for adding your comment on this. It clarified it more to me.
